# Format date in go lang from 2019-01-02 to 2019/01/01

Tags: go, strftime

Can someone help me how to format date in go lang from 2019-01-02 to 2019/01/01. This is my code so far

```
str := "2019-01-02 00:00:00"
//layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"

t, err := time.Parse("2006/01/02 15:04:05", str)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(t)
```

And It always throws `parsing time "2019-01-02 00:00:00" as "2006/01/02 15:04:05": cannot parse "-01-02 00:00:00" as "/"`

I saw tutorials but they are of not much use

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you're asking it to parse the input with the format you want for your output. It can't, because that's not the format of the input. You need to parse the input *in the format it's in*, then you can format it for output *in the output format you want*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse needs the format of str and next Format the time to expected format

```
str := "2019-01-02 00:00:00"
//layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"

t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05", str)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(t.Format("2006/01/02 15:04:05"))
```